# Details in existence of free groups proof (Clara Loeh,pg-22,23)

Tags: category-theory, free-groups, geometric-group-theory

I have **a few doubts in the proof of existence of free groups** given by Clara Loeh in page-22,23 of her [Geometric Group theory book](http://www.mathematik.uni-regensburg.de/loeh/ggt_book/ggt_book_draft.pdf).

> Theorem 2.2.7: Let S be a set. Then there exists a group freely generated by S. (By the previous proposition, this group is unique
> up to isomorphism.)

1. When the equivalence is defined in page-22, is it implicitly assumed that $ s$  and $ \hat{s}$ are inverses?

> $$\forall_{x,y \in A^*} \forall_{s \in S} xs \hat{s}y \sim y xy$$
> $$\forall_{x,y \in A^*} \forall_{s \in S} x \hat{s} s  y \sim xy$$

2. In page-23, Clara defines a function which help us define inverse for general words. Here is what she gave exactly:

> Inductively (over the length of sequences), we define a map $I:A^* \to A^* $ by $I(\epsilon) := \epsilon$ and
>
> 1. $I(sx) :=I(x) \hat{s}$
> 2. $I( \hat{s} x) : = I(x) s$

In the above why did she write 1. and 2.? Shouldn't just one of the equations be enough? My thinking is that in $A^*$ , $s$  and $\hat{s}$ are just elements in the set $A^*$.

Secondly, I am not sure if I understand this function in itself. Suppose I have a word $abc$ made up of letters $a,b,c$ then would it be correct to write $I(abc)= I(bc) \hat{a}$..? and then push it down till $I(abc)=\hat{c} \hat{b} \hat{a}$?

3. In page-23 (again), I am confused at the part where she defines $\varphi^*$ which map from the set to words to a group. The idea can be understood by the diagram:
   [image]

> For every group G and every map$ \varphi: S −→ G$ there is a unique group homomorphism $\varphi: F(S) −→ G$ such that $\overline{\varphi} ◦ i = \varphi$. Given $\varphi$, we construct a map
>
> $\phi^*: A^* \to G$
>
> Inductively by:
>
> 1. $ \epsilon \to e$
> 2. $sx \to \varphi(s) \cdot \varphi^*(x)$
> 3. $ \hat{s} x \to ( \varphi(s))^{-1} \cdot \varphi^*(x)$

Again I am confused, why we need both two and three..? I think one is enough for similar reason said before.

---

### Note:

1. Free groups are defined by their universal property in the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question: the proof of theorem $2.2.7$ explicitly explains what $\hat{s}$ is: it's an additional
disjoint copy of $S$ whose elements play the roles of inverses.  In fact, it's the very first paragraph of the proof.

For your second question: since $s\in S$ and $\hat s \in S$ are different (and belong to different, disjoint copies of $S$) we need to define how they both operate on the group element $x$, which is why both points $1$ and $2$ are given.
You can indeed go from $I(abc)$ to $\hat{c}\hat b\hat a$ and this is also the expected right-inverse of the word $abc$ in a group.

And for your last question the answer is again that this explicitly connects the nominal inverse $\hat s$ with the inverse of the homomorphism $\varphi$ so both need to be defined.

Comment: If the group is not commutative then knowing what $x\hat s$ is tells you nothing about $\hat s x$.  So you have to define both terms separately.  Nominal inverse means "that thing we are calling an inverse" because: $S$ is set and sets don't have inverses.  But if we can treat $S$ as a group, then it does, because groups are required to have inverses.  Since groups are also closed, all the inverses $\hat s$ of elements $s\in S$ must also be in $S$, so we can take a second copy of $S$ and treat them as in the inverses.  We're calling them inverses, but at this stage we haven't shown they are

Comment: I don't really understand what you're writing there I'm afraid.  $\hat s x$ and $x \hat s$ are different things, as Ms. Löh defines, and are on equal footing inasmuch as they are both words.

Comment: Ah ok!  I'm sorry, that's completely my fault; points one and two are not about commutativity (I won't bore you with the connection that made me write that); I've updated the answer to reflect that.  The issue is that $s$ and $\hat s$ belong to different copies of $S$ so we need to specify how they both behave with respect to $I$.

Comment: Could you explain right side of third eqtn? I am confused at $( \varphi(s))^{-1}$

Comment: If you have more questions you should really ask them as a new question and not keep adding them in comments.  However: the point of $3.$ is to establish that $\phi ^*$ is a homomorphism and that it interacts with $\hat s$ by inverses (because we intend $\hat s$ to be the inverse of $s$).  From $\epsilon = \phi(\varepsilon) = \phi(\hat s s) = \phi(\hat s) \phi(s) \Rightarrow (\phi(s))^{-1} = \phi(\hat s)$ (writing the homomorphism multiplicatively) being what we want we obtain $3$.